# can not see my view in Design Mode. Constraint Layout

Tags: android-constraintlayout

[image]

why I can not see my layout?

anybody help.

Answer (score 1):

Change AppTheme from NoActionBar to Anyone(Theme) in XML design.

Comment: how to do it? fadfalsdjfkajsdlfkaj

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the theme.
Select the theme Light:

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx2YW.png)